# Element exists or not in amazon dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Am using Amazon Dynamodb for my application, in docs they mentioned how to fetch an element already exists and if I try to fetch an element which is not present in db, its throwing an exception. We have to handle exception and presume its not contained or else is there any way to find whether db contains the value or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're fetching an item, you should be using getItem.

Query should be used when you don't have a range key and scan is when you don't have a hash key.

Comment: Thank you Chen. Yeah I got it and after fetching(getItem()) used isEmpty() to check whether it is null or not. Before accessed element that throws exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Query or Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html) () with limit set to one (Query, of course, is much more preferred). Then check how many items were found.

Comment: Thank you yegor256. Is Querying better option than GetItem?

Comment: `GetItem` is not suitable, as you already mentioned, since it throws an exception if an element is not found.